# Curl http_code return different values

Tags: bash, variables, curl

I'm trying to make an "intelligent" script that upgrade filebot jar file but I've some problems, the very 1st problem is that if I use curl to compare the online and local files sometimes the http_code that I receive is 304, sometimes 200 and this is not very helpfull!!!
First I generate a timestamp file with`stat -c %Y ...` But the problem is not here, all works except this, that sometimes return 200 sometimes 304, I think that is not a code problem, but maybe someone know a better way to do this

```
curl -s -k http://sourceforge.net/projects/filebot/files/filebot/HEAD/FileBot.jar -z "$(date --rfc-2822 -d @$(</opt/usr/share/fbot/FileBot.jar.timestamp))" -o /opt/usr/share/filebot/FileBot.jar -L -w %{http_code}
```

Just because I think that is a "normal" error and I can't fix it, I thinked to catch the http_code and if is 200 do some stuf, if is 304 other stuff and other ...

But I'm not able to declare a variable to the http_code with out re-download the file

I've this code

```
        if [[ "$(curl -s -k $FILEBOTURL -z "$(date --rfc-2822 -d @$(<$FILEBOTTIMESTAMP))" -o $TMPFILE -L -w %{http_code})" == "200" ]]; then
        echo "yep!"
        get_timestamp
    else
        echo "I can't download the FileBot jar, try again later"
        exit
    fi
```

As you can see in theory if http_code is 200 the file is downloaded and upgraded, only if the http_code is 304 the file is already updated. So my idea is to curl one time that I need and assign the http_code to one varialbe, then if the variable is 200 etc etc ...

I tried to do this

```
if [[ "HTTPCODE=$(curl -s -k $FILEBOTURL -z "$(date --rfc-2822 -d @$(<$FILEBOTTIMESTAMP))" -o $TMPFILE -L -w %{http_code})" == "200" ]]; then
```

But HTTPCODE is empty, so mission failed!

Any idea or suggestion?

J

---

Ok tnx rednoah, what do you think about this? I tried to make it "intuitive" so if the download file is not right or other don't do the update

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

CAT=$(which cat)
GREP=$(which grep)
FIND=$(which find)
RM=$(which rm)
MV=$(which mv)
ECHO=$(which echo)
FILEBOTPROGRAM=$(which filebot)
FILEBOTJAR=$($CAT $FILEBOTPROGRAM | $GREP -oP '(?<=-jar ).*(?= )')
FILEBOTDIR=$(dirname "${FILEBOTJAR}")
TMPFILE="$FILEBOTDIR/fb.jar"
FILEBOTTIMESTAMP="$FILEBOTJAR.timestamp"
FILEBOTURL="http://sourceforge.net/projects/filebot/files/filebot/HEAD/FileBot.jar"

#CLEAN
if [[ -f $TMPFILE ]]; then
    $RM $TMPFILE
fi

#FUNCTIONS
get_timestamp () {
    $ECHO -n "Info: Generating new timestamp for the jar ... "
    stat -c %Y $FILEBOTJAR > $FILEBOTTIMESTAMP
    $ECHO "done, happy file renaming with your upgraded FileBot"
    exit
}

update_check () {
    $ECHO -n "Info: Let's check if the Head of FileBot is updated ... "
    if [[ -f $FILEBOTTIMESTAMP ]]; then
        HTTPCODE=$(curl -s -k $FILEBOTURL -z "$(date --rfc-2822 -d @$(<$FILEBOTTIMESTAMP))" -o $TMPFILE -L -w %{http_code})
        if [[ $HTTPCODE == "200" ]]; then
            if [[ $($FIND $TMPFILE -type f -size +25M 2>/dev/null) ]]; then
                $MV $TMPFILE $FILEBOTJAR
                $ECHO "yep, downloaded and upgraded!"
                get_timestamp
            fi
            $ECHO "No new version of FileBot are available"
            exit
        fi
        if [[ $HTTPCODE == "304" ]]; then
            $ECHO "No new version of FileBot are available"
            exit
        fi
        if [[ $HTTPCODE == "404" ]]; then
            $ECHO "I can't download the FileBot jar, try again later"
            exit
        fi
    else
        $ECHO "I can't know if there's an update, so I'll perform a full update and I take note of this"
        HTTPCODE=$(curl -s -k $FILEBOTURL -o $TMPFILE -L -w %{http_code})
        if [[ $HTTPCODE == "200" ]]; then
            if [[ $($FIND $TMPFILE -type f -size +25M 2>/dev/null) ]]; then
                $MV $TMPFILE $FILEBOTJAR
                $ECHO "jar, downloaded and upgraded!"
                get_timestamp
            fi
            $RM $TMPFILE
            $ECHO "I can't download the FileBot jar, try again later"
        fi
    fi
}

recovery() {
    if [[ -f $TMPFILE ]]; then
        $RM $TMPFILE
    fi
    $ECHO "yep but don't works very well, I'll try to fix it! Please be patient"
    $ECHO ""
    $RM $FILEBOTJAR
    HTTPCODE=$(curl -s -k $FILEBOTURL -o $TMPFILE -L -w %{http_code})
    if [[ $HTTPCODE == "200" ]]; then
        if [[ $($FIND $TMPFILE -type f -size +25M 2>/dev/null) ]]; then
            $MV $TMPFILE $FILEBOTJAR
            $ECHO "jar, downloaded and upgraded!"
            get_timestamp
        fi
        $RM $TMPFILE
        $ECHO "I can't download the FileBot jar, try again later"
    fi
}

#THE SCRIPT
clear

$ECHO ""
$ECHO "============================================================="
$ECHO "               Filebot Auto-Updater script"
$ECHO "============================================================="
$ECHO ""

$ECHO -n "Info: Checking if FileBot jar exist ... "
if [[ -f $FILEBOTJAR ]]; then
    # so the file exist but I don't know if works correctly, so
    $FILEBOTPROGRAM $FILEBOTJAR -version || recovery
    $ECHO "yep and works like a charm, let's check if there are some update"
    $ECHO ""
    update_check
else
    $ECHO "I can't find FileBot, is installed?"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to a MWE?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what is MWE

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example

Answer (score 0):

There's a script for that in the FileBot portable package: 
https://github.com/svn2github/filebot/blob/master/installer/portable/update-filebot.sh

Comment: Ok, maybe I found a solution to the second question, I'm able to assign a variable during a if statement if [ "${HTTPCODE=$(curl -s -k $FILEBOTURL -z "$(date --rfc-2822 -d @$(<$FILEBOTTIMESTAMP))" -o $TMPFILE -L -w %{http_code})}" -eq 200 ]; then Is this correct? Or is a kind of miracle if works?!